spring security keeps redirecting me to spring login page
What ever link I type in the address bar it keeps redirecting me to the login page
my SecurityConfig:
package com.example.demo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth-> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form ->form
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                )
                .logout(config ->config.logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}


my home controller:
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping({"","/"})
    public String showHomePage(){
        return "index";
    }
}


I tried a lot of thing like disable csrf and a lot of thing it keeps seem issue
